# Is "assert I'm holding this mutex locked" Feasible?

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads, mutex

In *[The Tools We Work With](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/phk/thetoolsweworkwith.html)* the author of software Varnish expressed his disappointment to the new ISO C standard draft. Especially he thinks there should be something useful like "assert I'm holding this mutex locked" function, and he claims he wrote one in Vanish.

I checked code. It essentially like this:

```
struct ilck {
    unsigned        magic;
    pthread_mutex_t     mtx;
    int         held;
    pthread_t       owner;
    VTAILQ_ENTRY(ilck)  list;
    const char      *w;
    struct VSC_C_lck    *stat;
};


void Lck__Lock(struct ilck *ilck, const char *p, const char *f, int l)
{
    if (!(params->diag_bitmap & 0x18)) {
        AZ(pthread_mutex_lock(&ilck->mtx));
        AZ(ilck->held);
        ilck->stat->locks++;
        ilck->owner = pthread_self();
        ilck->held = 1;
        return;
    }
    r = pthread_mutex_trylock(&ilck->mtx);
    assert(r == 0 || r == EBUSY);
    if (r) {
        ilck->stat->colls++;
        if (params->diag_bitmap & 0x8)
            VSL(SLT_Debug, 0, "MTX_CONTEST(%s,%s,%d,%s)",
                p, f, l, ilck->w);
        AZ(pthread_mutex_lock(&ilck->mtx));
    } else if (params->diag_bitmap & 0x8) {
        VSL(SLT_Debug, 0, "MTX_LOCK(%s,%s,%d,%s)", p, f, l, ilck->w);
    }
    ilck->stat->locks++;
    ilck->owner = pthread_self();
    ilck->held = 1;
}

void
Lck__Assert(const struct ilck *ilck, int held)
{
    if (held)
        assert(ilck->held &&
            pthread_equal(ilck->owner, pthread_self()));
    else
        assert(!ilck->held ||
            !pthread_equal(ilck->owner, pthread_self()));
}
```

I omit the implementation of the try-lock and unlock operation since they are basically routine. The place where I have question is the Lck__Assert(), in which the access to ilck->held and lick->owner is not protected by any mutex.

So say the following sequence of event:

1. Thread A locks a mutex.
2. Thread A unlocks it.
3. Thread B locks the same mutex. In the course of locking (within
   Lck_lock()), thread B is preempted after it updates ilck->held but
   before it updates ilck->owner. That should be possible because of
   the optimizer and CPU out-of-order.
4. Thread A runs and invoke the Lck__Assert(), the assertion will be
   true and thread A in fact doesn't hold the mutex.

In my opinion there should be some "global" mutex to protect the mutex's its own data, or at least some write/read barrier. Is my analysis correct?

Comment: I can't see the unlock code.  I would assume it correct resets the owner.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that, given the breadth and complexity of multithreaded design and the problems associated with it, that the functionality offered by things like this, even if actually working on all platforms, are are not worth it.

Comment: I find the blog you are linking to a bit pathetic. His rant against using keywords like `_Noreturn` and aliasing them with `noreturn` just shows that he doesn't know much what it means to design a standard that is backwards compatible.

Comment: I checked the code more, and discovered it's indeed the unlock's unset of the owner make it work. The absent of a lock protecting ilck's own data is remedied by some tricks, though fragile but still working. So I would post some detailed analysis once I have time.

Comment: Hi Martin, the point making me interested in whether this works or not, is that, although it's not a silver-bullet, but it really could discover some out-of-order locking problem (so potential deadlock). What's your opinion about "not worth it"?

Comment: Hi Hans, I think I concluded too fast yesterday. I checked the code and find the wired thing. The unlock code does NOT unset the owner. Another problem is what means "unset". In POSIX, there is no definition of invalid value or invalid value range of thread ID. That means ANY integer value would be a valid thread ID. So I still can't think of a feasible solution for the required function.

Answer (score 0):

I have contacted the author. He says my analysis is valid and using a memset(,0,) to unset the "thread_t owner" as thread_t is not a transparent struct with specified assignment operator. Hope that works on most platforms.